# How do I identify slow queries in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, debugging

I've found long, complicated instructions [like this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/) when googling for the answer to this question, an brief reference links such as in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/40651/queries-run-extremely-fast-locally-extremely-slow-on-remote-machines/40660#40660).

I'm looking for a succinct a procedure as possible to generate a list of SQL queries with execution time where execution time > some_threshold.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess the answer wasn't here because it's so simple! Here's what I figured out:

1. Open **SQL Server Profiler** (in Performance Tools)
2. `File -> New Trace...`
3. Connect to your database
4. Click the Events Selection tab
5. Select only events which correspond to SQL queries finishing:

   - `RPC:Completed`
   - `SQL:BatchCompleted`
6. Click **Column Filters...**
7. Click **Duration** in the list
8. Expand **Greater than or equal** and enter the threshold time you consider "slow" in milliseconds
9. Click **OK**
10. Click **Run**

You can filter by `ApplicationName`, `NTUserName`, etc if you have a lot of applications running and want to cut down on noise. You can also show only some columns, e.g. just `TextData` and `Duration`.

Here's [a much more advanced treatment](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/) of the Profiler.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this to get the top 10 expensive queries (If you are on Sql server 2005 and above):

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
-- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a Profiler trace, particularly when importing the trace into a database, is an excellent methodology.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, DMVs (Dynamic Management Views) offer an alternative methodology:

```
SELECT TOP 100
(total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes) / qs.execution_count AS average_IO,
(total_logical_reads + total_logical_writes) AS total_IO,
qs.execution_count AS execution_count,
SUBSTRING (qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2, 
     (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
        THEN LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), qt.text)) * 2 
      ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) AS indivudual_query,
o.name AS object_name,
DB_NAME(qt.dbid) AS database_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) as qt
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o ON qt.objectid = o.object_id
where qt.dbid = DB_ID()
ORDER BY average_IO DESC;
```

One of the things to remember is that DMVs are cleared when SQL Server starts, so if your server has been up for 12 minutes it may not tell you a lot. Also, they are cumulative - so maintenance windows (checkDB) can skew the data.

Comment: Wow, what's the difference between this query and provided by @DaniSQL ?
It seems to produce really different results. THIS query mostly shows slow stored procedures for me. hm...